# How to retrieve numeric data as string

Tags: c#, string, enums

This kind question may be asked before, but I can't get my head around it, so I'll appreciate any help.

I have a message box where a type of error that i'm receiving by modbus communication is stored.

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error uploading: {0}", e.ReceivedData[0]));
```

`e.ReceivedData[0]` is holding the data that I want to show on the message box. 
So, it might be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. Those numbers represent type of operation failure.

However, I want to show the exact error message

```
1 - "UR_NOT_ACTIVE",
2 - "UR_OUT_OF_BOUND",
3 - "UR_INVALID_COMMAND"
```

and so on.

My plan was to store it in an enum, but I have no previous experience with c#, so it it more confusing than I thought.

Comment: *My plan was to store it in enum*: any code or problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use an `enum`:

```
public enum OperationFailureType
{
    UR_NOT_ACTIVE = 1,
    UR_OUT_OF_BOUND = 2,
    UR_INVALID_COMMAND = 3
}
```

Now you can use `enumValue.ToString` to get the text and you can cast it to `int` to get the number.

```
MessageBox.Show($"Error uploading: {e.ReceivedData[0].ToString()}");
```

Presuming `ReceivedData` is now an array of this enum. If it's just an `int[]` and you can't change it you can cast it to the `OperationFailureType`:

```
OperationFailureType failureType = (OperationFailureType) e.ReceivedData[0];
MessageBox.Show($"Error uploading: {failureType.ToString()}");
```

Comment: ``DisplayAttribute`` would be nice aswell - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tim Schmelter, thanks for the fast response. Safe my ass today, no more OOP for the rest of the week. :D